# Как перейти в "Settings" -> "Enable Go Modules" GO в VSC

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

Как в VSC перейти в "Settings"->"Go"->"Go Modules"->"Enable Go Modules Integration" для того, чтобы  включить VGO. Я новичек, и увидел, что если при импорте пакетов github (go get), компилятор их не видит, то следует включить vgo. Но как это сделать? Что не гуглю- все не то. У меня горит. Помогите пожалуйста. Благодарю.

Comment: ну так открываете меню file, там preferences и там уже будет settings. или просто жмете ctrl и запятую. И в открывшейся странице есть быстрый поиск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете стандартное расширение для Go в VSCode, то он все это видит из коробки и ничего настраивать не надо. Но для того, чтобы расширение стало видеть пакеты после `go get`, нужно сначала подгрузить сами зависимости.

Для этого попробуйте добавить нужные импорты и максимально простой код для взаимодействия с ними. Затем соберите проект (`go build -i`) или просто запустите его (`go run`).

После этого зависимости подгрузятся и автокомплит должен починиться.

Comment: Да в том и дело, что я ни через run не могу компильнуть, ни через build собрать, т.к импорт. с гитхаба пакет, содержащийся в конце пути сквозь 2-3 подкаталога(по URL адресу)- он тупо не видит. Зато если просто создать каталог в src, и поместить в этот каталог пакет- он его без проблем видит. Ладно, надеюсь, со временем решу. Благодарю)